# Calculate shortest paths for dart score checkout python

Tags: python

I want to create a python file that returns all the **shortest** paths given a certain dart score.
Import to note is that the last dart throw should be a double or a double bulls-eye (50).

This is what I got sofar

```
import re


SCORES = ['DB','SB','T20','T19','T18','T17','T16','T15','T14','T13','T12','T11','T10',
          'T9','T8','T7','T6','T5','T4','T3','T2','D20','D19','D18','D17','D18','D17',
          'D16','D15','D14','D13','D12','D11','D10','D9','D8','D7','D6','D5','D4','D3',
          'D2','S20','S19','S18','S17','S16','S15','S14','S13','S12','S11','S10','S9',
          'S8','S7','S6','S5','S4','S3','S2']


def caculate_numerical_score(score: str) -> int:
   if score == 'DB':
      return 50
   elif score == 'SB':
      return 25
   elif score.startswith('T'):
      return 3 * int(re.findall('\d+', score)[0])
   elif score.startswith('D'):
      return 2 * int(re.findall('\d+', score)[0])
   else:
      return int(re.findall('\d+', score)[0])
```

The above code transforms all the possible dart outcomes to an actual numerical score.
Now I need to loop over these scores and check which combinations result in the lowest amount of throws. I got the following incomplete code and need some help going forward...

```
def calculate_checkout(to_score: int):
   paths = []
   left_to_score = to_score
   throw = 1

   while left_to_score > 0:
      # throw
      paths[throw] = #  loop  over scores
      throw += 1
      left_to_score = to_score - sum(paths)
      if left_to_score % 2 and left_to_score <= 40 and left_to_score != 0:
         print(f'throw double and game is finished')
         paths[throw] = left_to_score / 2
         print(paths)
```

A 9-darter is the holy-grail in darts. In that case, you use only nine darts, the fewest possible, to check out from 501. So if we would use 501 as to `to_score`, the code should show the following (partial) output

```
['T20','T20'.'T20','T20','T20','T20','T20','T19','D12']
```

This is one of the 3944 [paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-dart_finish#/media/File:Nine-Dart_Paths.svg) that can be classified as a 9-darter. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a go at this as an integer program, using [python-mip](https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip), and it does produce solutions.
Unfortunately it only finds a single solution by default - it will need a bit of coercion to generate multiple sols.

Before this I knew literally zero darts rules. I don't know how to read that image you linked. so there are almost certainly some rules I didn't pick up with my few minutes of googling that need to be incorporated.

`pip install mip` for the optimsation library.

```py
import re
import mip
from pprint import pprint

SCORES = ['DB','SB','T20','T19','T18','T17','T16','T15','T14','T13','T12','T11','T10',
          'T9','T8','T7','T6','T5','T4','T3','T2','D20','D19','D18','D17','D18','D17',
          'D16','D15','D14','D13','D12','D11','D10','D9','D8','D7','D6','D5','D4','D3',
          'D2','S20','S19','S18','S17','S16','S15','S14','S13','S12','S11','S10','S9',
          'S8','S7','S6','S5','S4','S3','S2']


def caculate_numerical_score(score: str) -> int:
   if score == 'DB':
      return 50
   elif score == 'SB':
      return 25
   elif score.startswith('T'):
      return 3 * int(re.findall('\d+', score)[0])
   elif score.startswith('D'):
      return 2 * int(re.findall('\d+', score)[0])
   else:
      return int(re.findall('\d+', score)[0])


def main():
    score_to_value = {score: caculate_numerical_score(score) for score in SCORES}
    uq_values = list(set(score_to_value.values()))  # unique values of all scores

    value_to_scores = {value: set() for value in uq_values}
    for score, value in score_to_value.items():
        value_to_scores[value].add(score)

    # pprint(value_to_scores)
    for nthrows in range(9, 12):
        print(f"Solving for {nthrows} throws")
        m = mip.Model()

        # 2D array, where each row represents one throw.
        # The 1/0 values correspond to which value in the the ``uq_values``
        # array is associated with the throw.
        throws = [
            [m.add_var(var_type=mip.BINARY) for _ in uq_values]
            for _ in range(nthrows)
        ]

        # Each throw must have exactly one associated value.
        for throw in throws:
            m += mip.xsum(throw) == 1

        # Linear expression of the value (score) for each throw, for later use.
        linexpr_scores = [
            mip.xsum([value * b for value, b in zip(uq_values, throw)])
            for throw in throws
        ]

        # The last throw must have a score of less than 40
        m += linexpr_scores[-1] <= 40

        # The last throw's value must be an integer multiple of 2.
        # So, force throw to zero if that's not the case.
        for i, value in enumerate(uq_values):
            if value % 2 != 0:
                m += throws[-1][i] == 0

        # The sum of all throw scores must be 501
        m += mip.xsum(linexpr_scores) == 501

        m.verbose = False
        m.max_solutions = 100
        status = m.optimize(max_seconds=10)
        if status != mip.OptimizationStatus.OPTIMAL:
            print(f"optimisation status {status}")
            continue
        print(f"{status.name}, found {m.num_solutions} solutions")

        # Pull out solution 1/0 values
        throws_sol = [[float(x.x) for x in throw] for throw in throws]
        # Pull out the selected value index for each throw
        throws_idx = [
            [i for i, v in enumerate(throw_sol) if v > 1e-3][0]
            for throw_sol in throws_sol
        ]
        # Convert selected value index to a value for each throw.
        throws_val = [uq_values[throw_idx] for throw_idx in throws_idx]
        # Convert the throw values to scores
        throws_scores = [value_to_scores[throw_val] for throw_val in throws_val]
        print(throws_scores)

        # TODO: coerce program into generating more solutions (hmu)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Solving for 9 throws
OPTIMAL, found 1 solutions
[{'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'T18'}, {'T19'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'D15', 'T10'}]
Solving for 10 throws
OPTIMAL, found 1 solutions
[{'DB'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'T13'}, {'DB'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'S2'}]
Solving for 11 throws
OPTIMAL, found 1 solutions
[{'T20'}, {'D17'}, {'T17'}, {'T20'}, {'T20'}, {'T11'}, {'T13'}, {'T17'}, {'T19'}, {'S20', 'D10'}, {'T12', 'D18'}]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to think about my problem. Your code looks very neat. I see one thing, I would like to change. The last throw is not equal to 50. But the criteria is that it is a double and <=40.

`m += linexpr_scores[-1] % 2 == 0`  and `m += linexpr_scores[-1] <= 40` How would you incorporate this?

Comment: Just updated the answer to incorporate that. Still seems a bit off - any thoughts?

Comment: ah yes nice, thanks. I am trying to rewrite your code a bit. Because now the score (501) is hardcoded and the number of throws is also given. Ideally, I want to insert a score and let the script return the path with the least amount of number of throws.

Comment: I reckon you could write a model to find the shortest throw - but what I've done here works fine if you just iterate over nthrows = 1....n and the first nthrows that finds a feasible solution is the min number of throws.

Comment: I forgot that final score can also be 50... How would you include that

Comment: I would take out ``m += linexpr_scores[-1] <= 40`` and then modify the for loop with ``if value % 2 != 0:`` to incorporate that logic

Comment: @fishstix44 not sure if you are still active but I was wondering, what do you mean by HMU in your to-do?

Comment: @AlienDeg it's short for "hit me up"

Comment: haha I thought it was some package or algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been answered already but here is extended version (for 3 and less darts checkouts) that prints all possible solutions (excluding those where you can flip darts order like finishing checkout from 22 could be  (d2, d4, d5) (not optimal obviously) and order doesn't matter.

```
import itertools

fields = {"S1": 1, "S2": 2, "S3": 3, "S4": 4, "S5": 5, "S6": 6, "S7": 7, "S8": 8, "S9": 9, "S10": 10, "S11": 11,
          "S12": 12, "S13": 13, "S14": 14, "S15": 15, "S16": 16, "S17": 17, "S18": 18, "S19": 19, "S20": 20, "S25": 25,
          "D1": 2, "D2": 4, "D3": 6, "D4": 8, "D5": 10, "D6": 12, "D7": 14, "D8": 16, "D9": 18, "D10": 20, "D11": 22,
          "D12": 24, "D13": 26, "D14": 28, "D15": 30, "D16": 32, "D17": 34, "D18": 36, "D19": 38, "D20": 40, "D25": 50,
          "T1": 3, "T2": 6, "T3": 9, "T4": 12, "T5": 15, "T6": 18, "T7": 21, "T8": 24, "T9": 27, "T10": 30, "T11": 33,
          "T12": 36, "T13": 39, "T14": 42, "T15": 45, "T16": 48, "T17": 51, "T18": 54, "T19": 57, "T20": 60}


def get_checkouts(points_remain: int) -> list:
    outs = []

    for field in fields:
        if fields[field] == points_remain:
            outs.append((field,))
    for seq in itertools.product(fields, repeat=2):
        val = [fields[i] for i in seq]
        if sum(val) == points_remain:
            outs.append(seq)
    for seq in itertools.product(fields, repeat=3):
        val = [fields[i] for i in seq]
        if sum(val) == points_remain:
            outs.append(seq)

    outs = [tuple(sorted(seq, reverse=True)) for seq in outs]
    outs = [out for out in set(outs) if "D" in out[-1]]

    return outs


checkout = get_checkouts(8)

print(checkout)
```